# Expo upload:ios with Release Channels

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

If an Expo iOS app has been built using Expo with a specified release channel `prod-v1`

```
expo build:ios --release-channel prod-v1
```

how can we tell `expo upload:ios` to upload this build that is configured to pull updates from the release channel `prod-v1`?

*Using Expo SDK 34, expo-cli@3.0.9, node v12.6.0, Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.5*

---

`expo upload:ios` does not appear to have any parameters for specifying the release channel

**Output of `expo upload:ios --help`:**

```
$ expo upload:ios --help

  Usage: upload:ios|ui [options] [projectDir]

  Uploads a standalone app to Apple TestFlight (works on macOS only). Uploads the latest build by default.

  Options:

    --latest                                 uploads the latest build (default)
    --id <id>                                id of the build to upload
    --path <path>                            path to the .ipa file
    --apple-id <apple-id>                    your Apple ID username (you can also set EXPO_APPLE_ID env variable)
    --itc-team-id <itc-team-id>              App Store Connect Team ID (optional if there is only one team available)
    --apple-id-password <apple-id-password>  your Apple ID password (you can also set EXPO_APPLE_ID_PASSWORD env variable)
    --app-name <app-name>                    the name of your app as it will appear on the App Store, this can't be longer than 30 characters (default: expo.name from app.json)
    --sku <sku>                              a unique ID for your app that is not visible on the App Store, will be generated unless provided
    --language <language>                    primary language (e.g. English, German; run `expo upload:ios --help` to see the list of available languages) (default: English)
    --public-url <url>                       The URL of an externally hosted manifest (for self-hosted apps)
    --config [file]                          Specify a path to app.json
    -h, --help                               output usage information
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the `expo upload:ios` help, it defaults to the last/latest build for that app/slug. So if you just built using `expo build:ios --release-channel prod-v1`, you should be good to go. But if your latest build points to a different release channel, then you can go to your build history on the https://expo.io and get the id of the build that points to `prod-v1` or to whatever release channel you might want, and pass it as an argument for the `--id` option for the `expo upload:ios` command. It would look something like this:

```
expo upload:ios --id {id-of-target-build-here}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you build `iOS` on the '`prod-v1`' channel, it will be built with the latest version of `iOS` on the channel.

If you want to update your iOS app, you can publish it to the channel.

```
expo publish --release-channel prod-v1
```

Comment: @Nyxynyx If my answer was helpful, would you choose my answer?